# PyMuPDF (fitz) not properly closing files, resulting in PermissionError [WinError 32]

Tags: python, pymupdf

I can't figure out why I'm getting a PermissionError when trying to clean up some temporary pdf files that are no longer needed.

My script downloads a bunch of single page pdf's into a /temp folder, then uses PyMuPDF to merge them into a single pdf. At the end of the script, when the merged file has been created, a cleanup function is supposed to move the pdf's from the temp folder to a another folder so I can delete the temp folder. It's when everything else is done, at the end, that I get the permission error when trying to move the temp files.

I tried 2 methods to generate the pdf without leaving files open at the end: 1 as per the [fitz wiki](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/wiki/Inserting-Pages-from-other-PDFs) using `open()` and then `close()`, and the other using `with` to ensure that nothing was being left open unintentionally. I included a simplification of what I'm trying to do, which results in exactly the same PermissionError. Both methods I used are in there, which can be tried by commenting out either one of the methods when initiation the object. It is available with the folders and files as used in the script on [my github](https://github.com/flyingbelgian/TestPDFmergeandclean). The scripts assumes some things to be present as defined in the dubinit of the PdfOut class:

```
import os, fitz, time

class PdfOut:
    def __init__(self):
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        
        # 3 pdf files exist in the /temp folder
        self.files = ['pdf1.pdf', 'pdf2.pdf', 'pdf3.pdf']
        self.dir_in = os.path.join(cwd, 'temp')
        # /archive directory exists - this is where composite pdf will be saved
        self.dir_out = os.path.join(cwd, 'archive')
        # /raw directory exists - this is where single page pdf must be moved at the end of the script
        self.dir_store = os.path.join(cwd, 'raw')
        
        self.bookmarks = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
        self.file_out = "Combined_File.pdf"

    def writePDFusingClose(self):
            composite_pdf = fitz.open()
            for f in self.files:
                new_page = fitz.open(os.path.join(self.dir_in, f))
                composite_pdf.insert_pdf(new_page)
                new_page.close()
            new_toc = []
            page_count = 1
            for item in self.bookmarks:
                entry = [1, item, page_count]
                new_toc.append(entry)
                page_count += 1
            composite_pdf.set_toc(new_toc)
            composite_pdf.save(os.path.join(self.dir_out, self.file_out), deflate=True, garbage=3)
            composite_pdf.close()

    def writePDFusingWith(self):
        with fitz.open() as composite_pdf:
            for f in self.files:
                with fitz.open(os.path.join(self.dir_in,f)) as new_page:
                    composite_pdf.insert_pdf(new_page)
            new_toc = []
            page_count = 1
            for item in self.bookmarks:
                entry = [1, item, page_count]
                new_toc.append(entry)
                page_count += 1
            composite_pdf.set_toc(new_toc)
            composite_pdf.save(os.path.join(self.dir_out, self.file_out), deflate=True, garbage=3)
    
    def cleanUp(self):
        for file_name in os.listdir(self.dir_in):
            os.replace(os.path.join(self.dir_in, file_name), os.path.join(self.dir_store, file_name))
        os.rmdir(self.dir_in)

new_file = PdfOut()
new_file.writePDFusingClose()
# new_file.writePDFusingWith()
# time.sleep(10)
new_file.cleanUp()
```

As you can see I even tried putting in a 10sec delay to allow for any scanning or system background operations to finish, but it didn't make a difference. In fact I actually tried manually deleting the files in windows explorer while the 10sec delay was ticking and it told me the file was locked by Python (so not some other system process). This leads me to believe PyMuPDF/fitz somehow keeps those files open in the python process even though the use of `with` should cause it to relinquish the files when completed with that specific operation.

This is the error message it generates:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\GitHub\TestPDFmergeandclean\main.py", line 52, in <module>
    new_file.cleanUp()
  File "d:\GitHub\TestPDFmergeandclean\main.py", line 45, in cleanUp
    os.replace(os.path.join(self.dir_in, file_name), os.path.join(self.dir_store, file_name))
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:\\GitHub\\TestPDFmergeandclean\\temp\\pdf1.pdf' -> 'D:\\GitHub\\TestPDFmergeandclean\\raw\\pdf1.pdf'
```

Everything works as expected, the combined pdf is generated with the ToC in the folder where it's supposed to go, it's just the problem with the cleanup of the temp folder. For the life of me I can't find anywhere in the PyMuPDF documentation any other way of forcibly closing out docs other than with the use of .close() ...

Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong, or another suggestion to achieve the cleanup of the temp folder as I'm trying to achieve?

EDIT:

Once the main script completes I can manually move/delete the pdfs, indicating that they are indeed relinquished by Python when the script finishes. But that's kinda the point of my question, why can't I get Python to relinquish the files without having to end main.py and rerun another one? In my project I tried moving the cleanUp method to the main.py script and elsewhere, to separate it from the output.py (where the merged pdf is created), that didn't solve the issue unfortunately.

If you're interested you can see the full setup on my github (https://github.com/flyingbelgian/AU_AIP_crawler/tree/CombinePDF). In the project you will see that I also create temporary html files which are then moved to another folder without issue, even when cleanup was in the same .py as the creation of the temp html files. It's only the pdfs touched by PyMuPDF that appear to remain open even after calling .close() on them.

EDIT 2:

I added a more explicit

```
print("All methods completed, starting 20sec sleep")
time.sleep(20)
```

before the final cleanUp call, allowing me to check if the files are relinquished by PyMuPDF when all the pdf handling is completed.

This confirms that the files are being held open by Python and not some other windows process:
[image]

Comment: In my project I tried moving the cleanUp method to the main.py script and elsewhere, to separate it from the output.py (where the merged pdf is created), that didn't solve the issue unfortunately. If you're interested you can see the full setup on my github (https://github.com/flyingbelgian/AU_AIP_crawler/tree/CombinePDF)

Comment: I'm far from a master at anything programming, let alone sysinternals and/or nirsoft, so not sure how to go about that. I do know that when I try to delete or rename the files while the script is running, during the time.sleep(10), windows explorer pops up an error saying that "The action can't be completed because the file is open in Python"

Comment: That might be a final resort if there's no other way to explicitly close them in the script. The intention isn't to delete the temp files, but to keep them in a "raw" folder for future use: the script will see if any files changed and then send an email including the original (which would've been stored in raw during a previous run of the script) and the new file. But if deleting is the only solution I'll just have to resort to extracting pages from the merged pdf when needed :(
Still seems silly if there's no way to get PyMuPDF to relinquish files other than by killing the script.

Comment: The OpenedFilesView.exe tool indeed identified python.exe as the one having the file open. So back to the original issue: why doesn't python relinquish the file when passing .close() to the file object? Sounds like I have to look into the "dirty underhand" method to close the files if the proper ".close()" won't do what it's supposed to do ...